# Updating a canvas diagram based on user input

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I want to be able to create diagrams and drawings on the fly, using input from the user.

If I have 2 text boxes for width and height, i want to be able to draw a rectangle based on user entered values, if they change the value in the input fields i want the drawing to change.

is canvas capable of this? does it need to work along with javascript?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can listen for text-inputs and issue appropriate canvas drawing commands.

All canvas commands must be issued in javascript...so yes, javascript is required.

Here's annotated code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/f6E6Y/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    // get a reference to the canvas and context
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    // vars for current width and height of a canvas rectangle
    var width=50;
    var height=35;

    // references to the input-text elements 
    // used to let user change the rect width & height
    var $width=document.getElementById('width');
    var $height=document.getElementById('height')

    // set the initial input-text values to the width/height vars
    $width.value=width;
    $height.value=height;

    // call the draw command
    draw();

    // listen for keyup events on width & height input-text elements
    // Get the current values from input-text & set the width/height vars
    // call draw to redraw the rect with the current width/height values
    $width.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
        width=this.value;
        draw();
    }, false);

    $height.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
        height=this.value;
        draw();
    }, false);


    // draw() clears the canvas and redraws the rect
    // based on user input
    function draw(){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.fillRect(40,40,width,height);
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    Width:<input type="text" id="width"><br>
    height:<input type="text" id="height"><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```